# Yii2 BackOffice with API REST Implementation

Tags: angularjs, rest, yii2, frontend, backend

I have developed an app in Yii2 that is as a backoffice for a Travel Agency.

I have used the basic start template, and used gii (code generator) to create the CRUDS for the models (Hotels, HotelRooms, HotelImages, etc)

I also want to create two different front-end applications (one for retail, and the other for other agencies), and I thought to separate it from the backend (maybe an angular.js app) and get the info through REST could be a good approach.

So I want to use the API Rest based on the models made with gii.

How can I achieve this?
I have read this: 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html

and It says that I have to switch the controllers.

Currently I have (generated with gii)

**class HotelController extends Controller**

and reading the guide it says that I have to use

**class HotelController extends ActiveController**

but if I make this change, the backoffice does not work anymore.

What would be the best approach?

Make **another** APIHotelController that extends ActiveController?

Can I **merge** (in some sort of way) with the gii generated controller?

Any other way to achieve this separation of layers (back-front) ?

Thanks!

Comment: Create separate module for api.

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant solution I know so far to build a REST API Yii2 web app without messing up with the existent code or the routes configurations is by building a REST API as a separate sub-application containing MVC elements by itself, which means in Yii's world : as a [module](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-modules.html).

You already have a working code, accessible within the `web` folder, it has it's own [Entry Scripts](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-entry-scripts.html) within the `index.php` file, its own server configurations (`.htaccess` file if using *apache*) and its own app configurations within the `config` folder to which your app will depend before parsing your URL's and rendering your *view* files within their related `controllers` and `models`.

So the idea is to create a new `web` folder, lets call it `api` for example, with its own [Entry Scripts](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-entry-scripts.html) file, own server configurations, own `config` folder and own `controllers` extending the [ActiveController](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-activecontroller.html) class.

Then both, your `web` app and `api` service will share the same `models` files to validate, store or retrieve data.

Your app will move from this basic template based structure :

```
+ assets
+ config
+ controllers
+ models
+ views
+ web
...
```

To this new structure (*from the tutorial linked below*) :

```
+ web
+ config
+ controllers
...
+ api
  + config
  + modules
    + v1
      + controllers
  .htaccess
  index.php
```

You will need then to register your `api` service as separate module in order to work and being initialized by Yii.

Then you will use different URLs to get to your `web` app and related `views` or Rest `api` and related *json/xml* outputs respectively within `http://[your_path]/web/controller/action` or `http://[your_path]/api/v1/controller/action` (*url structure depends on your web and api configs*).

In order to implement the necessary code, here is a great [step by step tutorial](https://www.diggin-data.de/dd-cms/blog/post/view/id/1004/name/Creating+a+REST+API+for+Yii2-basic-template). It uses the basic template structure and follows yii's [api versionning](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-versioning.html) approach (*the `v1` folder*).

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation!