# 404 error with unknownclass exception in yii2

Tags: routes, namespaces, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am new to yii2. I have succesfully extracted the advanced yii2 zip template.
have set up the db and the .htaccess file.

On creating a new controller , model and action in the controller and navigating to the location. Eg: http://localhost/advanced/frontend/web/mysetofusers/signin

I face three issues.
1. it says 404 error.
2. says UnKnownClassException - ie Unable to find mysetofusersController in file  frontendControllers\mysetofusersController.php namespace missing??    even though the file is there in the folder and exact name space is use.
3. It always redirects to site/index page rather than showing up the mysetofusers/signin.   This time tehre is no exception in the Yii debugger.

a=Also note i have tried to create models using both gii and extended class of Model.

Nothing seems to work.
Pls help me out. I am stuck and not able to move ahead with the work.

Thanks:)

Comment: is it necessary to start with the advanced template ? it is highly recommended to start with the basic one, much easier to setup and easier to learn. Then when your app is almost done, moving your models, controllers and components to an advanced structure will be matter of copy/past and some extra configs that you'll understand their need by so far.

Comment: Its not. proj is neither small and since advanced had all the directory structure for backend/frontend /common and  asi was planning to create REST API thot its was ideal to use advanced template. haven't tried with basic yet. will do so. However if anyone has already had this prob please let me know the solution for it. Thanks!

Comment: Well what I'm saying is that it will not be hard to move your files from a basic to an advanced template at a further step. If you consider going with a basic one then [this link may help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31799470/yii2-backoffice-with-api-rest-implementation/31806478#31806478). That is how I restructure the basic template to implement a REST API within an `api` folder by keeping my `web` folder untouched, each have its own *controllers* & *configs* and both shares the same app *models*.

Comment: sure il try that then. Thanks salem:)

Comment: Hi Salem, On using basic template also i see 404 error. is it something related to urlManager. Eg: MyListUsersController      I have followed the link you have shared.     And my urlManager Says this                                                            'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,'rules' => [['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                'controller' => 'v1/MyListUser'],
                'POST api/web/v1/<controller:\w+>s' => '<controller>/create',

Comment: 'api/web/v1/<controller:\w+>s' => '<controller>/index',
'PUT api/web/v1/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/update',
 'DELETE api/web/v1/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/delete',
 'api/web/v1/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
'<controller:\w+>s/create' => '<controller>/create',
 '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<action:update|delete>' => '<controller>/<action>'],

Comment: and modules component                                                                                      'modules' => [  'v1' => ['basePath' => '@app/api/modules/v1',                'class' => 'app\api\modules\v1\MyListUser' ]],                                                                                                                              Could you please help me out.    folder structure is same as u have mentioned in the sample link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`404`** errors in Yii 2.0 usually came from wrong **urlManager** configs or **Server** configs.

Before creating the `api` module be sure that your REST app works after following [the official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html). If not then it is probably a Server config issue.

In order for REST to work, **pretty urls** must be enabled by configuring the `.htaccess` file ( *if using apache server* ) like so :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Then you can go for [restructuring your app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31799470/yii2-backoffice-with-api-rest-implementation/31806478#31806478).

This is a NOT YET COMPLETED but a [working repo](https://github.com/tunecino/Yii2_foundation-apps/tree/master/backend) where you'll find [the configs](https://github.com/tunecino/Yii2_foundation-apps/blob/master/backend/config/api.php) I used for the `api` folder and the [onces](https://github.com/tunecino/Yii2_foundation-apps/blob/master/backend/config/web.php) I used for the `web` folder + the two `.htaccess` files inside each of the two folders.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Im trying that. Could you tell me is it necessary to run the curl command that is mentioned in the "the official docs".  If so how is it the i can check. Im using windows OS. and i can see that there is a $ symbol there. Is this the only way to check if the rest app works?   Pls bear  as im totally new to the  REST yii concept.

Comment: No, the curl command is just one of different methods to test the REST service. You can go directly to the link `http://localhost/users` (*or whatever your project path is*) from your navigator. You should see your data retrieved from DB as XML outputs. If you get there the you are good, you can start restructuring your app. if not then check your Server Configs (*.htaccess*). Remember to add `s` for plurals (if your model name is `car` for example then your url should look like `http://[path_to_project]/cars` or maybe `http://[path_to_project]/web/cars` (depends on your *.htaccess* file) )

Comment: Hi Salem:) Tested it..  YO!! Basic yii is working fine.. apparently its because of the     'enableStrictParsing' => true, changed it to false and after setting rewrite_module and adding .htaccess in web Rest is actually working now!!    Its now a get going for the API module.  Kudos!

Comment: Great ! If you need to test your data with JSON output now rather than XML and don't want to use curl, there is great navigator extensions out there like [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) which you can use when testing REST.

Comment: sure. i have tested it in Postman. it returns json data. but seems like in yii it stays as XML response oly evn after setting  \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON; or CJSON::encode()

Comment: No, that depends on your request. Yii's REST is flexible. check the curl example again in [the quick start guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html). a request holding `Accept:application/json` in its header will bring you json results, and that's not the same as `Accept:application/xml`. It will just work fine with any front supporting REST.

Comment: Yeah i had set the header content type. Dont why it wasnt. But yeah now its returning the JSON data. Thanks Salem. Much help:)

Comment: Hi salem i also wanted to knw. how could i post the form to the rest api action. Or how can i test the rest api for creating a record in the dn. I know for this i have to add aquery string to the url. How do i add it to the api from the form submit and how do i test it in postman. here on calling the rest api with querysting in postman it says 404.  Do we need a url manager for this. or create a acton with default parameters?

Comment: Yes you need to configure your app routing within `urlManager[rules]` by declaring the accepted verbs otherwise Yii will throw a 404 error. See [REST Rooting - Yii2 official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-routing.html) for more details. And about testing with postman, here is a [quick video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JZP2ose-OBQ).

Comment: Hi Salem Querdani,     U there. Im facing a issue with the api. Nowehere to go for help. Can i have a chat with you for this? in stack overflow?                            Issues here is post man doesnt give any response but says Bad request. Although the url in browser returns the JSON response that im sending from the action.  Could you please let me knw how know if you have any idea. My doubts are increasing. Would be obliged if i can get in touch with you for these doubts. Thanks!!